# How to push another author's commit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I cherry-picked a commit from upstream and now I want to push it to my branch. When I try to, I get the following message:

```
remote: ERROR:  In commit 5a0d13ea359e2056c205aa46f57d5e80f6251296        
remote: ERROR:  author email address <other author's email>        
remote: ERROR:  does not match your user account.        
remote: ERROR:        
remote: ERROR:  The following addresses are currently registered:        
remote: ERROR:    <my email>        
remote: ERROR:        
remote: ERROR:  To register an email address, please visit:
```

Can I push the commit without changing the author's email or without adding their email to my email list?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You need to have "Forge Author Identity" permission in refs/* reference set in your project (or in some parent project like All-Projects):

[image]

Talk to the Gerrit administrator to ask this. See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_forge_author).

Comment: Thank you, I'll ask the administrator for such a permission since that's what I most likely need.

Answer (score 1):

You can **SOFT** reset this cherry-picked commit and commit it. So it will get your account email and name.

If the problem is that it is getting your account e-mail an name you can commit with --author="Author Name " of the author you want

Comment: That's "changing the author's email", though, which the OP specifically asked not to do.

Comment: "with --author="Author Name " of the author you want". OP can put the original author of the commit with this.

Comment: Tested with Gerrit Code Review (3.8.1), worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The "remote:" in front of each error message tells you that it's not *your* Git complaining, it's some *other* Git.  In this case, since you're running `git push`, your Git is relaying the complaint coming from the Git to which you're `git push`ing.

*Their* complaint is quite clear: you are the one doing the `git push`, and they—the other Git—have a list of author email addresses that they believe you should be allowed to use.  Commit `5a0d13ea359e2056c205aa46f57d5e80f6251296` (which is presumably the result of your `git cherry-pick` operation) lists some other email address as its author.  So the answer to:

> Can I push the commit without changing the author's email or without adding their email to my email list?

is clear: *no*, if you cannot change the set of checks that *their* Git runs; *yes*, if you can change the set of checks that *their* Git runs.

There's no *standard* way to change these things, so the answer is probably "no".  Gerrit does have a way to enable "forge author" permissions, as [described here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-invalid-author.html).  To set such a permission you must be the project owner.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for an extensive answer. I'll probably have to ask for the administrator's permission like Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira said.