# Why can't I checkout another two changes and make a new one

Tags: git, gerrit

My team is working with Gerrit.

Now, two colleagues and I are working on a some project.

Both of them have `git push` to Gerrit, meaning that there have been two independent Changes on Gerrit.

Now, I need to get their changes, merge them into my local project, and push a new Change to Gerrit.

Let's say the two existing changes are `A` and `B`.

On my local machine, I do things as below:

```
git checkout master && git pull
git fetch ... refs/changes/xx/xxxxxx/x && git checkout FETCH_HEAD # checkout A from Gerrit
git switch -c br_a
git fetch ... refs/changes/xx/xxxxxx/y && git checkout FETCH_HEAD # checkout B from Gerrit
git switch -c br_b
```

Now, I have two local branches `br_a` and `br_b`, which contain the changes `A` and `B`.

Then I switch to my own local branch, which contains my own changes: `git checkout br_c`.

After that, I do `git merge br_a` and `git merge br_b` to merge the changes of `A` and `B` into my local branch `br_c`. (I resolved all of conflicts.)

Then I need to push all of these to Gerrit.

So I execute `git commit` and `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`.

However, I got the error.

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (26/26)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
remote:
remote: ERROR:  In commit 1111111098b751266c11111222222a33ce0b83
remote: ERROR:  author email address B@xxx.com
remote: ERROR:  does not match your user account.
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  The following addresses are currently registered:
remote: ERROR:    me@xxx.com
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  To register an email address, please visit:
remote: ERROR:  http://gerrit.xxxx.yyyy.com/#/settings/contact
remote:
remote:
To http://gerrit.xxxx.yyyy.com/a/xxx_project
 ! [remote rejected]     HEAD -> refs/for/master (invalid author)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://gerrit.xxxx.yyyy.com/a/xxx_project'
```

`B@xxx.com` is one of the two colleagues, so it seems that `git merge` bring some metadata of `A` and/or `B` into my local branch so that I can't push.

I've tried `git commit --amend`, delete the Change-id and/or reset the author and email, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to push another author's commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004828/how-to-push-another-authors-commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerrit has 2 permissions, [Forge Author](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_forge_author) and [Forge Committer](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_forge_committer). When you push a commit for review, Gerrit validates if the author email and committer email match the email address registered in your Gerrit username. If they don't match, the push is rejected. You used `git merge` to apply commits. The author and committer identity lines are not changed, and don't match yours. So the push failed.

Here are 2 solutions. One is to ask the Gerrit administrator to grant you the 2 permissions so that you can push commits made by others. The other is to apply the patches without preserving the author and committer identities, by `git merge --squash` or `git cherry-pick -n` or `git apply` or manually modifying the files.